# Pass django variable to javascript file without security issues

Tags: javascript, django

**Clarification:**

> I really don't want to embed my `js` in my `html`. The suggestions I'm
>   getting, like, this or that post might contain the possible answer,
>   well in those answers, they embedded their `js` in `html`. Both my
>   `js` and `html` is large. So embedding will surely make them messy and
>   hard to debug

In my project there's a module where user can see details about product and add products to cart. For this he needs to specify the number of products he wants to add. It looks like 
[image: this]

For this I have a `+` and `-` icon. I have a `js` file where it increments or decrements each time `+` or `-` has been clicked.

Now, what I want is this:

> A user can add products but if the total number exceeds the number of
>   products stored in the database, he can't add products even if he
>   click the `+` button. For example, if there are 4 items and he clicked
>   5 times then on the 5th click the amount will remain 4, won't
>   increase.

So I need a django variable in my `js` file. I looked up how to do that, and I found some solutions.

Some solution says `var data = '{{data|escapejs}}'` this while some solution says

```
<script>
var myTable = {% autoescape off %}{{ table_data }}{% endautoescape %};
</script>
```

But I don't want to embed `js` on my `html` like this. Here is my `js` file:

```
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('quantity').value = value;
}
```

And my `html`, from where I am calling this `js` like this:

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-qty" onclick="incrementValue()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>
</span>

<input class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-qty" id="quantity" value="0" />

<span class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-qty" onclick="decrementValue()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
</span>
```

What is the best way to pass `django` variable to `js` or, How should I pass the `django` variable to my `js` so that there will be no **vulnerability** or no **security issues** and also I don't want to embed `js` in my `html`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass django context variables into javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009740/how-do-i-pass-django-context-variables-into-javascript)

Comment: I've already viewed those answer. My question differs from those. I've mentioned that I don't want to embed `js` in `html`. But those answer contains `js` embedded in `html`

Comment: And also, according to the link, @solarissmoke,  you gave, in your answer, you are sending dictionary from `views.py`. What I'm doing is I'm taking all the products from my `ProductList` model. Now, according to your answer, I've to find `the quantity of products` in the `views.py` and send it to `html`. Is it efficient?

Comment: @sphoenix I know this is a super old question, but do you mind sharing what did you end up doing ?